# filtering JSON using underscore

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, underscore.js

I got a JSON name collection like this:

```
[{

   "name":"Jim",
   "prize":"Nokia Mobile"
  },
  {

   "name":"Marry",
   "prize":"iPhone"
  },
  {

   "name":"Alice",
   "prize":"iPad"
  }

]
```

now I'd like to filter this JSON by a string: var data= "m";

so, this is what I've done:

```
    var data= "m";

    collection = _.filter(collection,function(c){


        return _.any(c,function(k){


            return k.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(data.toLowerCase()) != -1;

        });


    });
```

so, in this case, collection return elements which has m in their name.

However, I've got "Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined".

I tried to put an alert "alert(c.name);" before the last return, and it's return "undefined". It shouldn't be, isn't it?

what need I change to fix this?

Comment: That's not valid JSON... your values are missing quotation marks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this http://underscorejs.org/#filter

Try this:

```
var data= "m";

collection = _.filter(collection,function(myObject){
    return myObject.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(data.toLowerCase()) != -1;
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**: Seems like your core problem here is misunderstanding of the input and output of the underscore functions `any` and `filter`. I realised after writing my answer I'm not really even sure what your code should be doing - but reading the docs for [filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) and [any](http://underscorejs.org/#some), along with the points below and in the rest of the answers, will surely help you solve your problem in the right way.

---

You shouldn't use `_.any` here - that tells you if *any* element in an array passes a test (implemented as a function which you pass to it). You shouldn't use `_.any` at all here, if you need to test `name`, just test `name` directly on the object.

`_.filter` is all you want - this returns a new array containing all elements from the passed in array which pass the test (likewise, implemented in the function you pass). In this case, all the objects where the `name` string contains the `data` string. See the code below for clarity on how each `element` from `collection` is passed and used inside the test function passed to `_.filter`.

Another point - if you can't guarantee the integrity of the data coming into `collection`, to avoid errors you should check first if the name property is defined - if it's not, fail the test.

```
var collection = [
   {
      "name":"Jim",
      "prize":"Nokia Mobile"
   },
   {
      "name":"Marry",
      "prize":"iPhone"
   },
   {
      "name":"Alice",
      "prize":"iPad"
   }];

var data = 'm';

collection = _.filter(collection,function(element){
    return element.name && element.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(data.toLowerCase()) != -1;
});
```

Also, you don't need to lowercase `data` here - you know it's lowercase - unless that `data = 'm'` declaration is just a placeholder for some other, unpredictable, input :-)

Comment: You *can* use `_.any` on an object - Underscore collection methods work on both objects and arrays.

Comment: Yeah indeed, I'll rewrite that bit - what I meant to say was OP is using it incorrectly on an object in this scenario, as it's unclear what they're trying to acheive

Comment: Thank you danvicwil for this detailed illustration

Answer (score 0):

True your JSON in the example isn't valid, the strings do need quotes as meager pointed out.

If it where valid and you wanted to filter the array using underscore I would use something like this

http://underscorejs.org/#filter

```
var data = 'm';
var filteredcollection = _.filter(collection, function(item){ 
    return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(data) != -1; 
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I think he wants to filter by name, in this case item is the entire Object.

Answer (score 0):

You have made it too complicated, simply:

```
var data = [{
   "name":"Jim",
   "prize":"Nokia Mobile"
  },
  {

   "name":"Marry",
   "prize":"iPhone"
  },
  {

   "name":"Alice",
   "prize":"iPad"
  }
];

var fiterTerm = "m";

var collection = _.filter(data, function(item){
    return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(fiterTerm.toLowerCase()) != -1;
});

console.log(collection);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put quotes round your values. And then: _any function with an object as collection passes 2 parameters to the callback function rather than one.

```
_.any({ name:"Jim", price: "Phone" },function(value,key) {
  alert(value+" "+key)
});
```

Will give you alerts with "Jim name" and then "Phone price". so you do not have to use the .name property on the value parameter.