# Autocomplete function with underscore/JS

Tags: search, filter, autocomplete, underscore.js

what is the proper way to implement an autocomplete search with undescore?

i have a simple array (cities) and a text input field ($.autocomplete). when the user enters the first letters in the auto-complete textfield, it should output an array with all the cities starting with the entered letters (term).

cities:

```
["Graz","Hamburg","Innsbruck","Linz","München","Other","Salzburg","Wien"]
```

eventlistener:

```
$.autocomplete.addEventListener("change", function(e){
  var cities = cities_array;
  var term = $.autocomplete.value;
  var results = _.filter(cities, function (city){

    return 

});
console.log(results +  "this is results");
});
```

I’ve tried it with _.contains, but it only returns the city when its a complete match (e.g Graz is only output when „Graz“ is entered but not when „Gr“ is entered).

the _.filter/._select collection at http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html are not very clear for me and the closest i found here is [filtering JSON using underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008635/filtering-json-using-underscore).

but i don’t understand the indexOf part.

thx for any suggestions!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By using `#filter` and `#indexOf`, you can get quite close to a pretty decent autocomplete.

What `#indexOf` does is that it checks the string if it contains the `inputVal`.
If it does not contain it it'll return `-1` therefore our predicate below will work without fail.

Another small trick here is that you (read I) wanted it to be possible to search for `s` and get a hit for `Innsbruck` and `Salzburg` alike therefore I threw in `#toLowerCase` so that you always search in lower case.

```
return _.filter(cities, function(city) {
    return city.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputVal.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
});
```

Comment: For better performance: transform inputVal to lower case outside the filter (its the same inputVal, shouldnt do this over and over again)